# OS X Directory Services

Tags: osx, ldap, kerberos

I have been reading from *Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment* (Stevenson and Rago), and I am currently reading about how user data is stored on various systems, including Linux, FreeBSD, and Mac OS X.

One of the interesting things mentioned was how various user data, like UID and passwords on FreeBSD and Mac OS X, don't follow the same storage format as `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` on most Linux distributions.

I was particularly curious about the Directory Services daemon used by Mac OS X and how it works to organize this data. For example, what kind of fields are in this database? How does the OS use this for permissions? How do developers interface with it? I couldn't seem to find much in the way of an explanation of how this service works, and would be grateful for any explanations or recommendations on readings on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple Open Directory is a fork of OpenLDAP plus Kerberos with some extra Apple sauce thrown in. Fields would thus likely be typical LDAP entries; I'd have to dig around to see where and how they are hiding anything Kerberos related. The interface would be via anything Apple-specific (e.g. see API docs under Xcode) or via the standard unix interfaces mentioned by Stevens (only twiddled with to work appropriately with Apple's backend).